# Customizer_register theme options not saving

Tags: theme-development, theme-options, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a phone field to a theme's customizer, so far, I was able to add the field in the customize page, but for some reasons, it won't save, whenever I save and went back to check it, the field phone is always blank

I'm just following along some guides from google, but it's not working. Am I missing any additional steps? Are there usual stuffs that prevent this from displaying correctly?

here is the functions.php customize_register

```
function psht_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'psht[phone]', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control('psht[phone]',
        array(
            'settings' => 'psht[phone]',
            'label'      => __( 'Phone Number' ),
            'section'    => 'title_tagline',
            'type'       =>  'text',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'psht_customize_register' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to it. To those who have the same problem, the solution is not to put a type.